# In Crystal Report, Memo field is not displaying complete data

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Report, Memo field is not displaying complete data it is trucating to 260 characters. I have googled alot and tried, but still no success.

Any suggetions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this question still needs answered, please rephrase to include more detailed information. Are you pulling this from a database field? If so, what type of database? What is the data-type of the field? My initial guess is that you rounded up to 260 characters from 255. If so, and your data-type for that field is varchar then the ODBC driver is truncating the data in the field at import into the report - you would need to be pulling from a text field data-type to avoid this